# No Fargate configuration exists for given values for Jenkins amazon-ecs-plugin

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ecs

I am trying to use recently released amazon-ecs-plugin:1.15 which support fargate but I am getting below error.

```
WARNING: Slave {0} - Cannot create ECS Task
May 24, 2018 1:10:39 PM hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner$2 run
WARNING: Unexpected exception encountered while provisioning agent ECS Slave ecs-jenkins-slave
com.amazonaws.services.ecs.model.ClientException: No Fargate configuration exists for given values. (Service: AmazonECS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ClientException; Request ID:****-****)
```

[Here is my config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9U2Oz.png)

Answer (score 73):

Check your CPU and memory amounts; you need to follow specific combinations:

```
CPU value       Memory value (MiB)
256 (.25 vCPU)  512 (0.5GB), 1024 (1GB), 2048 (2GB)
512 (.5 vCPU)   1024 (1GB), 2048 (2GB), 3072 (3GB), 4096 (4GB) 
1024 (1 vCPU)   2048 (2GB), 3072 (3GB), 4096 (4GB), 5120 (5GB), 6144 (6GB), 7168 (7GB), 8192 (8GB) 
2048 (2 vCPU)   Between 4096 (4GB) and 16384 (16GB) in increments of 1024 (1GB) 
4096 (4 vCPU)   Between 8192 (8GB) and 30720 (30GB) in increments of 1024 (1GB)
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-cpu-memory-error.html

Comment: This worked for me using terraform - the error message was the same "No Fargate configuration exists for given values"

Comment: this also worked for me. Didn't realize that there is a constrain between CPU and Memory value.

Answer (score 16):

To add to [user6327093's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54526354/10907864)

I had a similar issue when trying to create resources on AWS ECS using Terraform. The error was:

> Error: ClientException: No Fargate configuration exists for given values.

**Here's how I fixed it**:

You must adhere to the supported task CPU and memory values for tasks that are hosted on Fargate are as follows.

| CPU value | Memory value (MiB) |
| --- | --- |
| 256 (.25 vCPU) | 512 (0.5GB), 1024 (1GB), 2048 (2GB) |
| 512 (.5 vCPU) | 1024 (1GB), 2048 (2GB), 3072 (3GB), 4096 (4GB) |
| 1024 (1 vCPU) | 2048 (2GB), 3072 (3GB), 4096 (4GB), 5120 (5GB), 6144 (6GB), 7168 (7GB), 8192 (8GB) |
| 2048 (2 vCPU) | Between 4096 (4GB) and 16384 (16GB) in increments of 1024 (1GB) |
| 4096 (4 vCPU) | Between 8192 (8GB) and 30720 (30GB) in increments of 1024 (1GB) |

In my case, the **CPU** was **4096**, while the memory was **32768 (32GB)**. However, **32768 (32GB)** memory is not supported by Fargate from the table above, so I had to change the **memory** to **30720 (30GB)**.

**Resources**: [Invalid CPU or memory value specified](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-cpu-memory-error.html)

**That's all**

Comment: Are these still valid in 2022?

Comment: Yes @jtlz2 it is still valid

Answer (score 0):

when deploying app using AWS COPILOT, got:

```
An ECS task definition to group your containers and run them on ECS              [delete complete]     [3.4s]
    Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: Create T
    askDefinition: **No Fargate configuration exists for given values: 512 C
    PU, 512 memory**. See the Amazon ECS documentation for the valid values.
     (Service: AmazonECS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ClientException; R
    equest ID: 6db81468-6c2a-404c-a97c-a03d59053523; Proxy: null)" (Reques
    tToken: 9cb92f50-d7a5-6473-6cb4-2073a165bf8b, HandlerErrorCode: Invali
    dRequest)
```

Solved by changing in manifest.yml under the relevant copilot service folder:
from "cpu: 512" to "cpu: 256", like below:

```
# Number of CPU units and memory (in MiB) allocated to each task.
cpu: 256
memory: 512
```

Refer to: https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/manifest/lb-web-service/

Combinations of CPU and Memory must be like answer above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54526354/3502900